# Ubuntu 18.04.04 on Orcle VirtualBox cannot detect sdcard

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, usb-device

I am working on some embedded project on Ubuntu 18.04 that is located on Oracle Virtualbox 6.0.24. My host is Windows 10 pro.

When I insert an SD-card (I have a Sandisk USB card reader) I see that only Windows detects it, not Ubuntu. I the past I was able to detect it with Gparted tool (shown as `/dev/sdb`).

I think some drivers have been changed in Windows or in Ubuntu. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange behavior.

I wanted to uncheck and then check "sandisk sddr" in *VM settings* --> *USB* --> *USB device filter*

When I uncheck this option, Ubuntu detects the SD card.